# How do I parse the output of the find command when filenames have spaces in them?

Tags: linux, find

Using a loop such as

```
for i in `find . -name \*.txt`
```

will break if some filenames have spaces in them.

What technique can I use to avoid this problem?

Comment: Note that files can also have newlines in their file name. That's why there's `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ideally you don't do it that way at all, because parsing filenames properly in a shell script is always difficult (fix it for spaces, you'll still have problems with other embedded characters, in particular newline). This is even listed as the [first entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) in the BashPitfalls page.

That said, there is a way to almost do what you want:

```
oIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

find . -name '*.txt' | while read -r i; do
  # use "$i" with whatever you're doing
done

IFS=$oIFS
```

Remember to also quote `$i` when using it, to avoid other things interpreting the spaces later.  Also remember to set `$IFS` back after using it, because not doing so will cause bewildering errors later.

This does have one other caveat attached:  what happens inside the `while` loop may take place in a subshell, depending on the exact shell you're using, so variable settings may not persist.  The `for` loop version avoids that but at the price that, even if you apply the `$IFS` solution to avoid issues with spaces, you will then get in trouble if the `find` returns too many files.

At some point the correct fix for all of this becomes doing it in a language such as Perl or Python instead of shell.

Comment: I like the idea of just using Python to avoid all this.

Answer (score 12):

Use `find -print0` and pipe it to `xargs -0`, or write your own little C program and pipe it to your little C program.  This is what `-print0` and `-0` were invented for.

Shell scripts aren't the best way to handle filenames with spaces in them: you can do it, but it gets clunky.

Comment: Works on my machine^TM !

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "internal field separator" (`IFS`) to something else than space for the loop argument splitting, e.g.

```
ORIGIFS=${IFS}
NL='
'
IFS=${NL}
for i in $(find . -name '*.txt'); do
    IFS=${ORIGIFS}
    #do stuff
done
IFS=${ORIGIFS}
```

I reset `IFS` after its use in find, mostly because it looks nice, I think. I haven't seen any problems in having it set to newline, but I think this is "cleaner".

Another method, depending on what you want to do with the output from `find`, is to either directly use `-exec` with the `find` command, or use `-print0` and pipe it into `xargs -0`. In the first case `find` takes care of the file name escaping. In the `-print0` case, `find` prints its output with a null separator, and then `xargs` splits on this. Since no file name can contain that character (what I know of), this is always safe as well. This it mostly useful in simple cases; and usually is not a great substitute for a full `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I  disagree with the `bash` bashers, because `bash`, along with the *nix tool set, is quite adept at handling files (including ones whose names have embedded whitespace).

Actually, `find` gives you fine grain control over choosing which files to process... On the bash side, you really only need to realize that you must make you strings into `bash words`; typically by using "double quotes", or some other mechanism like using IFS, or find's `{}`

Note that in most/many situations you do not need to set and reset IFS; just use IFS locally as shown in the examples below.  All three handle whitespace fine. Also you do not need a "standard" loop structure, because *find's* `\;` **is** effectively a loop; just put your loop logic into a bash function (if you aren't calling a standard tool).

```
IFS=$'\n' find ~/ -name '*.txt' -exec  function-or-util {} \;
```

And, two more examples

```
IFS=$'\n' find ~/ -name '*.txt' -exec  printf 'Hello %s\n' {} \;  
IFS=$'\n' find ~/ -name '*.txt' -exec  echo {} \+ |sed 's/home//'
```

'find`also allows you to pass multiple filenames as args to you script ..(if it suits your need: use`+`instead`\;`)

Comment: There is some validity to both perspectives.  When I was only working on my own files, I would just use find and not worry about it, because my files don't have spaces (or carriage returns!) in their names.  But when you start working with other peoples' files, you have to use more robust techniques.

Answer (score 1):

## Using `find -print0` with `xargs -0`

Using `find -print0` combined with `xargs -0` is completely robust against legal file names, and is one of the most extensible methods available. For example, say you wanted a listing of every PDF file within the current directory. You could write

```
$ find . -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 echo
```

This will find every PDF (via `-iname '*.pdf'`) in the current directory (`.`) and any sub-directory, and pass each of them as an argument to the `echo` command. Because we specified the `-n 1` option, `xargs` will only pass one argument at a time to `echo`. Had we omitted that option, `xargs` would have passed as many as possible to `echo`. (You can `echo short input | xargs --show-limits` to see how many bytes are allowed in a command line.)

### What does `xargs` do, exactly?

We can clearly see the effect `xargs` has on its input — and the effect of `-n` in particular — by using a script which echoes its arguments in a more precise manner than `echo`.

```
$ cat > echoArgs.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of arguments: $#"

[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && exit

for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
    echo "Arg $i: <$1>"
    shift
done
EOF

$ find . -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 ./echoArgs.sh
$ find . -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ./echoArgs.sh
```

Note that it handles spaces and newlines perfectly well,

```
$ touch 'A space-age
new line of vending machines.pdf'
$ find . -iname '*space*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ./echoArgs.sh
```

which would be especially troublesome with the following common solution:

```
chmod +x ./echoArgs.sh
for file in $(ls *spacey*); do
  ./echoArgs.sh "$file"
done
```

Notes

- [How to print “$” in here-document](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68440/8503)